# Access C# overloaded method from C++/CLI managed

Tags: c#, c++, .net, managed-c++

I have C# class library with interface

```
public interface IInterface
{
    public IObject Get(SomeClass a);
    public IObject Get(SomeClass a, SomeClass1 b);
    public IObject Get(SomeClass a, SomeClass2 c);
}
```

In my C++ managed code i need to call third method with SomeClass2 arg.
But VS show me an error

```
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'SomeClass2 ^' to 'SomeClass1 ^'
```

Is it possible to call overloaded method from C++?

Comment: don't you mean c++/cli?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any problems doing this (can't put this in a comment):

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
   public class SomeClass {}

   public class SomeClass1 {}

   public class SomeClass2 {}

   public interface IInterface
   {
      object Get(SomeClass a);
      object Get(SomeClass a, SomeClass1 b);
      object Get(SomeClass a, SomeClass2 c);
   }

   public class Implementation : IInterface
   {   
      public object Get(SomeClass a)
      {
         return null;
      }

      public object Get(SomeClass a, SomeClass1 b)
      {
         return null;
      }

      public object Get(SomeClass a, SomeClass2 c)
      {
         return null;
      }
   }
}
```

And the C++/CLI code

```
using namespace System;
using namespace ClassLibrary1;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
   auto o = gcnew Implementation();
   o->Get(gcnew SomeClass());
   o->Get(gcnew SomeClass(), gcnew SomeClass1());
   o->Get(gcnew SomeClass(), gcnew SomeClass2());

    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles without problems.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But if both projects are not in one solution, and C# part is release it shows and accepts just one of methods

Comment: Ok, so I removed the class library from the solution, built its Release config, added an assembly reference to the DLL (not the project) and still works very well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that one of arguments is System::DateTime which is value type, and in my code i declared it as reference

```
System::Date^ date = ...
```

When i changed it do value type it become possible to call any method. Why it called without any problems method with reference typedatetime i dont know

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. This was taking me a long time and it would have taken longer if not for this.